# How to refresh DataGrid when item is edited

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to a viewsource as follows:

```
   public OrderProcessingEntities ctx = new OrderProcessingEntities();
    private CollectionViewSource customerViewSource;

    public CustomersDataSheet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        customerViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource) this.FindResource("customerViewSource")));    
        ctx.Customers.Load();
        customerViewSource.Source = ctx.Customers.Local;
    }
```

Each record on the DataGrid has a button that opens another form (`EditForm.ShowDialog()`) for editing that record.

The edit form has its own connection in the same way as it's parent form with the DataGrid.

The user can save or cancel. If he saves I use `ctx.SaveChanges()` to save the changes to the database (Sql Server).

What do I need to do, so that the DataGrid gets refreshed with the updated data.

I can do this when the EditForm closes, but I don't want the row position of the DataGrid to change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.

You need a INotify class to let the Datagrid know your source has been changed, here is what I use.

```
public class CommonBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'd create a ViewModel for your page that has the datagrid, this view model will have your CustomerViewSource like below. I'll call it CustomerView. You want to inherit from the CommonBase class we created above. Can use a CollectionViewSource or ObservableCollection.

```
 public class CustomerView: CommonBase
 {
  private CollectionViewSource _CustomerViewSource;
  public CollectionViewSource CustomerViewSource
    {
        get { return _CustomerViewSource; }
        set { _CustomerViewSource = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerViewSource"); }
    }
  public void GetCustomers()
   {
     CustomerView = new CollectionViewSource()
     //YOUR CODE HERE TO POPULATE CustomerView

   }
 }
```

In your XAML, Set the DataContext with the below code. "ViewModels" is just the folder I have the CustomerView in , in my project.

```
  <DataGrid.DataContext>
     <ViewModels:CustomerView x:Name="CustomerView"></ViewModels:CustomerView>
   </DataGrid.DataContext>
```

And set your DataGrid Item source in XAML to our ViewSource

```
ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerViewSource}
```

Now in your code behind when you populate the grid or on Form Load, you will go like this. This will populate the list and update the grid. Now whenever that List gets added to or whatever, the grid will refresh.

```
CustomerView.GetCustomers();
```